# эффект по ссылке

Tags: css

Есть ссылка, её длина зависит от ее содержимого. Возможно ли при hover увеличить ее длину на 20px например, при том, что длина ссылки всегда разная ?

https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/JMapzR

```
<a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</a>

a {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно, чтобы визуально border-bottom вытягивался вправо на 20px? Если да, то вот так:

```css
a {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  transition: .5s;
}
a:hover {
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#linkWrapper {
  width: 320px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  background: red;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

#linkWrapper:hover a {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="linkWrapper">
  <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</a>
</div>
```

Comment: длина ссылки всегда разная, фикс длину я тоже могу задать ))

Comment: Ну сделай `width: auto;`

Comment: И по твоему увеличение   `padding-right` лучшее решение?)))  детский сад....

Comment: @Air, а что не так с padding-right? :)

Comment: @humster_spb )))  ничего, все просто супер....

Comment: а, что решит width: auto ? как мне width: auto увеличить на 20px при наведении ?))

Answer (score 0):

```
a::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
}
a:hover::after {
  width: 40px;
}
```